# TFS Online Build Fails on local Build Server with TF270016 / TF270002

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

We're using Visual Studio Online, but we have local Build Controller and Build agent.  This has been running fine for the past 6 months or so, but just this week the builds have consistently failed.

The software itself appears to build successfully, and the tests also seem to pass, but it fails due to an error during the publication of the log files (see error below).

The build uses an unmodified Default Template, and is setup so that it "does not copy output files to a drop folder" (in the Build Defaults of the build definition).

After a few hours of head-banging this feels like some sort of permissions thing, but I have no idea how to go about debugging, or verifying this assumption.

Can anyone offer any suggestions, or better yet, a solution! :-)

One other thing to note is that we have been mucking about with our users in Visual Studio Online to change some accounts from Basic to Stakeholder accounts in order to reduce costs.  I'm wondering if we've also managed to remove a critical account or permission that has caused this...?

**Error**

```
An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. 
Details: TF270002: 
    An error occurred copying files from 
    'C:\Users\tfs\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent\5498\Logs\2853\LogsToCopy\ActivityLog.AgentScope.5498.xml' 
    to 
    'ActivityLog.AgentScope.5498.xml'. 
Details: BadRequest: Bad Request

An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. 
Details: TF270002: 
    An error occurred copying files from 
    'C:\Users\tfs\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildController\4592\Logs\2853\LogsToCopy\ActivityLog.xml' 
    to
    'ActivityLog.xml'. 
    Details: BadRequest: Bad Request
```

**Edit**
One thing to note is that this error is consistent across all builds for different C# projects that are executed through the same build controller.  I've tried removing and re-registering the controller, restarting the build service and the build server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this (in my case anyway) was to upgrade the Build controller software to v12 (TFS 2013).

Answer (score 0):

we are also experiencing similar issue. We have not done any changes to VSO permissions, so I doubt it is that.

Two things that coinside this:
1. There was an update to VSOnline during the same timewindow that this issue appeared
2. Our local build controllers/agents were updated with latest Patch Tuesday updates

Comment: I've just noticed that our Build controller software is v11.0 (2012), so I wonder if there is an incompatibility issue?  I've started building a new build server with v12.0 (2013) to see if this helps...