# TFS Builds Partially Succeeding After Upgrade

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We just updated from TFS2010 to TFS2013 and everything went well with the exception of one reoccurring error.

An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: TF270002: An error occurred copying files from 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildController\3\Logs\109925\LogsToCopy\ActivityLog.xml' to 'ActivityLog.xml'. Details: ServiceUnavailable: Service Unavailable

We are seeing this on very build.  Two things just out
1.) The error says Details: ServiceUnavailable: Service Unavailable, what service?
2.) The file path listed does not exist of the server.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this previous post would be useful:

[TFS Online Build Fails on local Build Server with TF270016 / TF270002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406687/tfs-online-build-fails-on-local-build-server-with-tf270016-tf270002)

Have you updated the build controller and all build agent servers to 2013?